X-meta learner and the CATE estimator
In X-learner the treatment sample and the control samples are imputed using the apprpriate model (the treatment sample response is imputed using the control sample and vice versa for the control sample).
Then two models are used for the estimation of CATE, one for each set of imputed values (usually combined using the propensity score). I'm adding the pseudo code for the X-learner taken from Kunzel et al. 2019.

Why do we use to separate CATE models? Why not combine all of the imputed outcomes and fit a single model (weighting the observation using the inverse propensity for example). Are there works that explore this idea?

The X-learner and T-learner both use separate models for each treatment group to predict expected outcomes as functions of covariates. This approach generally provides better treatment-specific estimates than the S-learner, which employs a single model for both groups and can struggle in cases of heterogeneous treatment effects. However, the X-learner offers an additional advantage by focusing explicitly on estimating the conditional treatment effect. It does this by combining the outcome models adaptively, weighting them by propensity scores to account for imbalances in the covariate space. This ensures that areas with fewer treated or control samples are better handled, leading to more robust estimates. In contrast, the T-learner does not incorporate such adaptive weighting, making it prone to bias and instability when treated and control groups are imbalanced.
In summary, the two-models approach makes the X-learner more suitable to capture treatment effect heterogeneity, and its propensity weighting makes it adaptive to data imbalance.

+1 but we should note that the X-learner is not always better than the T-learner. Yes, if one of the two treatments is rare, then the X-Learner should be more preferable than the T-Learner but on the other hand, if we believe that the CATE function is equally or more complex than the response functions or the groups are relatively balanced, then a T-Learner approach can outperform an X-Learner approach. Ch. 15 "Estimation and Validation of Heterogeneous Treatment Effects" from the book "Applied Causal Inference Powered by ML and AI" by Chernozhukov et al. is a great reference on the matter.
